# Cannot install Checkstyle plugin on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, checkstyle

I would like to install the Checkstyle plugin on Eclipse but keep getting this error.

[image: my error message]

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Can you open the [URL mentioned in the error message](https://checkstyle.org/eclipse-cs-update-site/compositeContent.xml) in a web browser?

Comment: Could you let me know how to check if I'm behind a proxy. I tried install checkstyle by Eclipse Marketplace and it still says the same thing. I cannot open the URL in the error message in a web browser. It's 404 file not found.

Comment: Really? [`https://checkstyle.org/eclipse-cs-update-site/compositeContent.xml`](https://checkstyle.org/eclipse-cs-update-site/compositeContent.xml) works for me in a web browser.

Comment: It works for me now but I still get that error. Is it something with my firewall or anti-virus software?

Comment: Yes, that could be the case.